# Remove anchor from url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’ve got a catalog with many items. If an items is clicked, it’s data is loaded in the popup via an ajax request  add an anchor is appended to the url. 
For example url is: site.com/catalog and after an item is loaded to the popup it becomes site.com/catalog/#id_product999
How to remove anchor url after popup closing? There is an event handler on the button that closes button:

```
$('.close-popup').on('click', function() {
    $('.popup-box').fadeOut();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [window.history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) to manipulate browser history. Try:

```
$('.close-popup').on('click', function() {
    window.history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
    $('.popup-box').fadeOut();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Great solution! Thx!